# Pointer with java and string variable

Tags: java, string

I gave a value (as variable) to a String variable.

The problem is that when I change this value, it doesn't change the other variable :

Code :

```
 String test = "hello";
 String myname = test;
 test = "how are you ?";
```

The output of **myname** is "hello"

I want that the output be "how are you?" the new value of test; how to do it without give the value again like :

```
myname = test;
```

I don't want to give the value again because I my code I got a lots of variables that got the **test** variable as value, I want to do the shortest way.

Answer (score 9):

First you are assigning the value "hello" (at some place in memory) to `test`:

```
test --------------> "hello"
```

Then, you are setting `myname` to the *same* location in memory.

```
test --------------> "hello"
                  /
myname ----------/
```

Then, you are assigning the value "how are you?" at a *new* location in memory to `test`:

```
                   -> "hello"
                  /
myname ----------/

test --------------> "how are you?"
```

It's all about the pointers.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

I have no idea what the rest of your code looks like, but if you want to be able to update a single String and have the rest of the references to that String update at the same time, then you need to use a `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer` if you need synchronization) instead:

```
    StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("hello");
    StringBuilder myname = test;
    StringBuilder foo = test;
    StringBuilder bar = test;
    test.replace(0, test.length(), "how are you?");
    Assert.assertEquals("how are you?", test.toString());
    Assert.assertEquals("how are you?", myname.toString());
    Assert.assertEquals("how are you?", foo.toString());
    Assert.assertEquals("how are you?", bar.toString());
```

Got it from there?

Comment: yeah Sure, but how to solve my problem

Comment: Thanks you for you answer, I hope it will help someone, but I took the answer unfortunately delete by this owned ('fox' something) wich was about using the arrays methods.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to learn about the difference between a reference variable and the object that a variable refers to. Let's look at what your code does:

```
String test = "hello";
```

This assigns the reference variable `test` to refer to a constant `String` object with the value `"hello"`.

```
 String myname = test;
```

Now the reference `myname` refers to the same `String` object as `test` does.

```
test = "how are you ?";
```

Now `test` refers to a **new** `String` object with the value of `"how are you ?"`. Note that this does not change `myname`, as you have seen.

Comment: sure I see that, that why Im asking for help to solve my problem

Comment: @user2372006 Perhaps you are asking the wrong question then. What exactly *is* the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `String` is immutable so `"how are you ?"` is a new object. Thus `myname` still refers to the old object `"hello"`.

Solution 1: Don't use two references. Why not just use `test` throughout your code if there's only one object?

Solution 2: Have the two references point to the same object, but use a mutable object. e.g. use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead of `String`.

Comment: the same code with a StringBuilder will have exactly the same result.

Comment: For your solution 1 : I said this is just a exemple, my code does have a lot of objects !

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent hours thinking i forgot how pointers worked. Coming from C, I was super confused why the String/Integer classes behaved differently than my own class. Found out that's cus Strings and Integers have the "final" keyword in the class declaration, making them immutable. As you probably know in C, when you've got "int*" you can modify the value pointed by the pointer, so I assumed Java would have that behavior, since Integer objects are pointing to integers. Thank you so much. I also found out 1 of the reasons is to make those classes thread-safe. Very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

That's how variables work. Variables are not references to other variables. They're references to objects. If you change what one variable references, it doesn't change what the other variabes reference.

You can change the content of an object though:

```
public class Container {
    private String value;
    // setter and getter omitted
}

Container test = new Container();
test.setValue("hello");
Container myname = test;
test.setValue("how are you ?);
System.out.println(myname.getValue()); // prints "how are you ?"
```

Comment: Thanks you for you answer, I hope it will help someone, but I took the answer unfortunately delete by this owned ('fox' something) wich was about using the arrays methods.

Answer (score 2):

Each of your variables is only a *pointer* to a real object. So after line 2, both variables point to the very same string. After line 3, `test` points somewhere else, and `myname` still points to the string.

There is no way to modify a Java String once it has been created.

To get what you want, you might use `AtomicReference<String>` as the data type for your variables. You don't really need the `Atomic` part of the reference, but it's the simplest reference type built in into Java.

Comment: Thanks you for you answer, I hope it will help someone, but I took the answer unfortunately delete by this owned ('fox' something) wich was about using the arrays methods.